# SyntaxError: invalid syntax href = 'http://maps.google.com' + href

Tags: python, compiler-errors

```
def download_if_dne(href, filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
#        print 'already downloaded:', href
        return False
    else:
        if not href.startswith('http://'
            href = 'http://maps.google.com' + href
            print 'Fixed url :', href
        try:
            print 'downloading:', href
            oa = openanything.fetch(href)
            if oa['status']==200:
                file = open( filename, 'w' )
                file.write( oa['data'] )
                file.close()
            return True
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            raise
        except:
            print '\tdownload failed -', sys.exc_info()[0]
            return False
```

This code is an edit to the software ogmaps.
http://code.google.com/p/ogmaps/issues/detail?id=1

Error message:

```
  File "ogmaps.py", line 36
    href = 'http://maps.google.com' + href
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not a python person and can't figure out the reason for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if not href.startswith('http://'` should be `if not href.startswith('http://'):`

Comment: The += won't work - it will create the string with the components in the wrong order.